# Distributing k balls to n boxes so that each box has at most one ball

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a question:

In how many ways can we distribute $k$ balls to $n$ boxes so that each box has at most one ball?

On can write the problem this way: The number of integer solutions to the equation $x_1 +x_2 +\cdots +x_n =k$ under the condition $0\leq x_i \leq 1$ for all $i=1,\ldots n$.

I know that the number of integer solutions to the equation $x_1 +x_2 +\cdots +x_n =k$ under the condition $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i=1,\ldots n$ is ${n+k-1 \choose k}$. But I don't know how to solve the equation with the condition $x_i \leq 1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it only a matter of selecting the $k$ boxes that receive one ball?

Comment: @drhab Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @drhab Do you mean it is enough to choose $k$ objects from $n$ objects? ${n \choose k}?$

Comment: You know the number without the restriction $x_i\leq 1$, so maybe you can find the number of solutions satisfying $x_i>1$ for some $i$ and substract to it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Usually if there are extra conditions like $0\leq x_i\leq m$ then things are more complicated. But on this the special case $m=1$ is an exception. There are just two sort of boxes (containing a ball or not containing a ball) and also it is clear how many of them will contain a ball (this equals the number of balls).

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right. Got it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer Thank you so much for the comment. Do you mean we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: Yes, but as @drhab has pointed, since our constrain is quite easy $x_i\leq 1$ there are easier methods. But in general, using the inclusion-exclusion principle you will be able to do the exercise.

Comment: One thing that’s not clear from your question.  Are the balls distinguishable or identical?

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer In that case, the problem turns into the equation $x_1 +\cdots +x_n=k-2n$ with $x_i \geq 0$. So the answer of this equation is ${n+k-2n-1 \choose k-2n}$. So we the answer of main question is ${n+k-1 \choose k}-{n+k-2n-1 \choose k-2n}$. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite, where does n-2k comes from? I don't understand you

Comment: @RobertShore They're identical, actually.

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer As you told, we can find the number of solutions satisfying $xi\geq 2$ for some $i$ and substract to it. So we put 2 balls in each box first, so we have $k-2n$ balls remained.

Comment: No, notice that the wrong cases are the ones where there exists some $i$ with $x_i\geq 2$, hence if there is one box with more than 1 ball this is already imposible (all the other boxes can be empty or have just 1 ball)

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer Yes, you are correct. I understood completely. Thank you so much for your consideration.

Comment: The answer is $\binom{n}{k}$ if the balls are indistinguishable.  If the balls are distinct, the answer is $P(n, k) = \binom{n}{k}k!$ since there are $k!$ ways of arranging $k$ distinct balls in the selected boxes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Got it. Thank you very much for your consideration.